# Is inheritance of navigation properties supported?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Having difficulty finding relevant search results...

**Given this model:**

```
public abstract class A
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
}

public class C : A
{
}

public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}
```

**With this configuration:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<A>().ToTable("As");
    modelBuilder.Entity<B>().ToTable("Bs");
    modelBuilder.Entity<C>().ToTable("Cs");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**I get this result in the DB:**

[image: Database]

**Question:**

Is inheritance of navigation properties not supported? If I add `public string SomeSharedProperty { get; set; }` to `A` then as I would expect the column for that property only showed up in the `As` table.

What reason is there for the `Customer_ID` column in the `Bs` and `Cs` table? Is there any way to tell EF to not map that inherited property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, inheritance is supported. But it seems in this specific instance not as you would expect.

Since Relational DBs do not support inheritance as we know it from object oriented programming there has to be some kind of transformation in order to make it happen.

Here is a series of blog post covering the issue in detail:

- [Table per hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)
- [Table per type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)
- [Table per class](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)

It also tries to give guidelines when to use which of the strategies.

**UPDATE**
Apparently this is more tricky than it seemed at first glance. What you see is most likely due to a circular reference: `A -> B -> Customer -> Bs`.

The `CustomerID` columns of Bs/Cs are NOT the inherited ones from the As Table. It is in fact the representation of the relation properties specified on the `Customer` class:

```
public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
```

results in a **nullable** `CustomerID` column on table B.

```
public virtual ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
```

results in a **nullable** `CustomerID` column on table C.

So those nullable columns are used to represent the relation `Customer -> Bs` and `Customer -> Cs`. Their appearance has nothing to do with the `Customer` property on the `A` class.

You can easily check this by removing the navigation properties of the customer class. Then the result is what you would expect: A `CustomerID` column on the A table and no `CustomerID` column on B / C Table.

So in order to solve this you need to specifically tell EF how to resolve the circular reference. Not sure this is possible though, I'm afraid you will need to omit the Bs/Cs properties on the `Customer` and write a LINQ query instead to retrieve the info.

If you need those properties on the `Customer` class you can do is something like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // this is necessary to have access to the related Bs/Cs
    // also it cant be private otherwise EF will not overload it properly
    public virtual ICollection<A> As { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<B> Bs { get { return this.As.OfType<B>(); } }
    public IEnumerable<C> Cs { get { return this.As.OfType<C>(); } }
}
```

Comment: You can see in my configuration that I am using TPT inheritance mapping. I've read all those articles before. My specific question is why the CustomerID foreign key column appears in all 3 tables and if there is any way to prevent that from happening.

Comment: My guess is that by making the Customer property `virtual` you cause the EF to assume that the relation might be handled differently on B and C and therefore it moves the property to those classes as well, try removing the `virtual` keyword if you don't want this to happen.

Comment: Doesn't work means it doesn't compile or it doesn't produce the SQL Tables you are expecting? Again, it is not wrong how it is done now, it's just different than what you would expect. The hierarchy is properly transformed. Is this a requirement to be different or do just feel it's wrong as it is done now?

Comment: It doesn't change the SQL tables. It is wrong how it's done. The whole point of using TPT is to normalize your data. There's no reason for 3 CustomerID properties. There should only be one on the As table.

Comment: It's not actually a inheritance issue, the properties you are seeing are to represent the relation between `Customer -> Bs/Cs`. I have updated my answer to reflect the tests I ran to confirm that this is indeed whats happening.

Comment: +1: Good analysis! Just a remark: Problem is not that much a *circular* reference but that EF always searches for pairs of navigation properties in the **declared** types to establish an association. It doesn't consider inheritance trees for navigation property pairs. Example: EF sees that in `Customer` is a property of type `ICollection<B>`, then it looks if in `B` is a reference/collection of type `Customer`. It doesn't look into any inherited properties, only into properties which are really declared in `B`. Hence `Customer.Bs` and `A.Customer` do not form a pair = 2 relationships = 2 FKs.