# EF code first - inheritance and relationships

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Please take a look at following code:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntityA : SomeEntity
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntityB : SomeEntity
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntityA> SomeEntitiesA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntityB> SomeEntitiesB { get; set; }
}
```

My question is - is there a way to set the FluentApi to make relationships shown above work properly? Currently when new SomeEntityA object is being added to User, EF creates a new record in SomeEntities table with properly set User_Id FK, however in SomeEntitesA which is an inherited table, there's also a FK property User_Id - set as null and when I try to get SomeEntitesA collection from User object - it's empty. I do realize why that happens, but I'm not sure whether there's a way to fix this? The only solution that comes to my mind at this moment is to replace following code:

```
    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntityA> SomeEntitiesA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntityB> SomeEntitiesB { get; set; }
```

with:

```
    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntitiesA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntitiesB { get; set; }
```

and configure FluentApi.

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this question/answer, the classes have exactly the same structure as yours and there is a detailed explanation why things are not working as expected:

[Is inheritance of navigation properties supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648109/is-inheritance-of-navigation-properties-supported)

As Slauma pointed out, there is a rather simple solution to get around this by doing the following (copied from the linked answer and fit to your example):

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Username { get; set; }

    // this is necessary to have access to the related SomeEntityAs/SomeEntityBs
    // also it cant be private otherwise EF will not overload it properly
    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SomeEntityA> SomeEntitiesA { get { return this.SomeEntities.OfType<SomeEntityA>(); } }
    public IEnumerable<SomeEntityB> SomeEntitiesB { get { return this.SomeEntities.OfType<SomeEntityA>(); } }
}
```

Comment: BTW: You could bring the solution (last code snippet) from your other answer to the question here. Because it's a real alternative. It will always load all base entities though and `OfType` then filter out in memory, so there is potential data loading overhead. But on the other hand you have the `User` in the base class and not "duplicated" in the derived classes like in my solution. By all means an interesting solution and worth to consider! (I will upvote :))

Comment: Thanks I think I'll stick to this approach but I'd like to know more about it's performance? Even if I change IEnumerable<SomeEntityA> to be type of IQueryable and for example use Take() method is it still going to load all these entities into memory first?

Comment: @Spetz No, not all all. Only the entities you request will be loaded. `OfType` gets translated into actual SQL, as does `Take`. So only the records you want will be returned from the DB, this is a very efficient approach

Comment: @Spetz and ntziolis: **Nooooo**, not true! This code will definitely load **all** `SomeEntity`s, A and B as well, due to lazy loading (`virtual`). The `OfType` filter for A happens **after** all entites are loaded in memory and just throw away the entities of type B. And you cannot replace it by `IQueryable` since you don't have the context availabe in your entity object. You could create such filters in a repository or service class, but not as property in the entity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I think I'll just use proper methods in the service layer to maintain the good performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed solution also won't work because you cannot relate two navigation properties `User.SomeEntitiesA` and `User.SomeEntitiesB` to the same endpoint `SomeEntity.User`. You would actually need two users:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserAId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SomeEntitiesA")]
    public virtual User UserA { get; set; }

    public int UserBId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SomeEntitiesB")]
    public virtual User UserB { get; set; }
}
```

But then you could also keep the collection types as they are and move the users to the derived entities:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntityA : SomeEntity
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class SomeEntityB : SomeEntity
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntityA> SomeEntitiesA { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SomeEntityB> SomeEntitiesB { get; set; }
}
```

You don't need to specify the `[InverseProperty]` in this case because conventions will detect now the correct pairs of navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the main idea is to keep the User in a base class, so when I create a View to show these entities, I can display username as well regardless of class being of type A or B.